# Word to describe someone who goes to all the events in town!

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, synonyms

I'm looking for a short word that could describe people who are always going to every event in town. It doesn't need to be an existing word, feel free to create one of your own. It can also be made of words related to events and parties. (ex: club, event, guest list, etc.)

**Edit**

The word will serve as a new term to describ these people in a favorable way. It will probably be used for an app name so it need to be catchy and fun. ( Preferably )

Comment: ***event-goer***

Comment: I use **"high-serotonin"** as an adjective to describe people who are unusually sociable, outgoing, exceptionally confident, optimistic, a delight to be around, successful, and comfortable in all situations. If only we all had such an abundance of positive neurotransmitters. Of course, *too much* serotonin has its dangers as well, but I still like and admire "high-serotonin" people.

Comment: event titillant?

Comment: Event-crawler..

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You may be looking for ***socialite***:

> someone who is well-known in fashionable society and is often seen at
>   parties and other social events for wealthy people

([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/socialite))

Comment: Words or phrases which I can think of are quite dependent on whether the speaker thinks it is a desirable trait; eg there is quite a difference between saying that someone would 'attend the opening of an envelope' and saying that they are 'a great supporter of local events'. Although I've never heard it used I like the idea that in the pejorative instance someone might become known as a 'Paper-knife'. As in 'That Fred is a real paper-knife, you can't so much as open an envelope without him being there.'

Comment: +1 - Also, "social butterfly" for middle-class afficionados.

Comment: With @oldbag's suggestion, you could perhaps call your app just "Butterfly", and since it's social media related, it's like a social butterfly

Comment: Kind if like the idea with the butterfly @BruceWayne maybe the name of a beautiful butterfly?

Comment: @spookypancake - Hm yeah a specific butterfly could work. However I caution using too specific a word, as most apps have a single word name. You could call the app Butterfly, but then "in" the app use the picture/name of a specific one.

Answer (score 18):

## gadabout

> A habitual pleasure-seeker.

I think this is a great, fun word that doesn't get enough play.

Comment: This is the first one that came to my mind as well.

Comment: This IS a good word... it makes me wonder if it's related to **gadfly**.

Answer (score 13):

You may be looking for  **party animal**

> (informal) someone who ​enjoys ​parties and ​party ​activities very much and goes to as many as ​possible: *Sarah's a ​real ​party ​animal - she ​likes to ​dance all ​night.* — [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/party-animal)

Answer (score 6):

[***Man About Town***](http://www.abbreviationfinder.org/fr/acronyms/mat_man-about-town.html)

> A man who frequently attends fashionable social functions, as in *Fred is quite the **man about town** these days*. This expression, first recorded in 1734, uses town in the sense of “a sophisticated place” as opposed to rural settings.
>
> [The American Heritage® Idioms Dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/man--about--town)

Comment: *Man about town* is certainly a fine expression (albeit gender-specific), but I don't think I've ever seen the acronym *MAT* before now.

Comment: This is the first thing I thought of, though it unfortunately is gender specific.  I suppose you could use "Woman about town", but I've never heard that expression, much less anything gender-neutral.  "Person about town"?  Just doesn't have the same ring to it.

Answer (score 4):

**Eventgoer** (or event-goer) — [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/event-goer)

> One who attends an event.

This should work just like **partygoer** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/partygoer)

> a person who attends a party or who attends parties frequently
>
> "*chauffeured transportation was provided for those partygoers who had overindulged themselves at the bar*"

The **-goer** suffix — [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/goer)

> a ​person who goes to the ​stated ​type of ​place
>
> *"Restaurant-goers ought to ​complain more about ​bad ​food and ​service."*
> *"regular ​filmgoers"*

Answer (score 3):

The way I've heard such people described is as "social butterflys"

Answer (score 3):

**event**eur - from **entrepre**neur

Comment: Is this a real term, or did you make it up?

Comment: it's made up did you like it?

Comment: Yes, but answers are intended to have sources (like in a real dictionary).

Answer (score 2):

my millenial daughter uses the term FOMO.  It's a person who suffers from a severe Fear Of Missing Out.

Comment: I like it.  But my dictionary says "FOMO" is actually the fear of missing out, not the person who suffers from this fear.  So we don't say "She is a FOMO," but rather "She has FOMO."

Comment: A good answer, but you don't get my upvote until you add more detail, maybe a source, fix grammar, etc.

Comment: agree. pretty good answer, but she doesn't get my upvote either, even if  she straightens out the errors and adds all the sources in the world

Answer (score 0):

Glitterati popped into my head, although it might just apply to the smartly dressed attendees.

Answer (score 0):

How about "over-attender" or "social-lot?" (socialot?)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a little dated, but "[a man about town](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/man--about--town)" could be used.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [**bon vivant**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bon%20vivant) is what you're looking for?

> a person who likes going to parties and other social occasions and who enjoys good food, wine, etc.